# How to push private files

Tags: git

I have a public project on Github, it's an Ansible role.
In this project, there is many files which are public, and 2 or 3 that are private (mainly private variable files).

I don't really want to push vaulted files, I'd like to maintain this role as clear for users as it can be (I provide cleared example for these files).

The solution I can think of is :

- 1st repo with only public files
- 2nd repo with public & private files

Git hook (or other solution) to push easily on both remote at same time.

What's the bests practices for this situation ?

Comment: Don't push private files in a public ansible versionned role. Put those files in your private project using the role.

Comment: You could include a submodule for a private directory.

Comment: Why not just `.gitignore` the files and never add them to the repository?

Comment: @phd If I just add them to my `.gitignore` and never add them, I can't do versionning on these files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @rolf82 and @Zeitounator, the best practice seems to be to maintain a private role and include my public role as a submodule.